# Closing tx stuck in mempool

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

I'm running core lightning 23.11. I have a channel closing tx stuck in the mempool:

https://mempool.space/tx/9245a9fc09ada2b1709d6f83ed2fa0875c91996a4c81eb6a03e84946f13c1042#flow=&vin=0

How can I bump the fee?

Comment: There is no easy way to rbf a transaction, but it is possible with the low lever API

Comment: Can you give me some pointers for how to do that?